# Enable disable CSS style on different page particularly *, html, body tags

Tags: css

```
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }



html, body {
  font-size: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #141414;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.2;


}

main { 
  margin : 0;
  padding: 0;;
}
```

The above css (containing wildcard, html, body, main) I am importing into components in my app, **no css module used**. Issue is they conflict with styles on a different route and page which use its own css.

Its not an external stylesheet like `<link rel='stylesheet' id=`, so it doesnt have an `id` and it just appears as `<style type="text/css">...</style>,...` in `<head>`

**Question:**
The above css I want to enable only on one route, for example I want it on page `/a` but I want to reset or remove them completely on page `/b`. How do I achieve that?

I also saw  [React Routes - different styling on body css tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641996/react-routes-different-styling-on-body-css-tag/37642310#37642310) and [How to apply CSS to HTML body element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582551/how-to-apply-css-to-html-body-element)

Comment: What I would do is add `!important` to the styles that are similar. e.g in component specific css `body{padding: 0 !important;}`

Comment: I dont know if i understand you correctly, but you can just apply a class "page-a" on your body and then add css for this class.

Comment: what if I go back to the previous page. I dont want the `!important` to override the wrong style. it has to toggle correctly

Comment: @ent3 if i have a `.page-a` class how do i include the `*, *::after, *::before` in the named css block?

Comment: Are you using some framework? Because if not then you can simply not have the css in the head of the pages you do not want it to be there... And to answer your question in the comments, you can do it like so: `.page-a *, .page-a *::after, .page-a *::after`. This means that everything inside `.page-a`, etc.

Comment: Within `.page-a` you only specify exceptions. `*, *::after, *::before` should applay anyways. I am not sure tho, if you can override for example `.page-a *::after` because of asterisk... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632100/apply-css-style-to-child-elements#comment76794481_10743992

Answer (score 1):

There are different solutions for this but best one seems like adding different class names for body in first mount of component and removing this class names in unmount. Other solution would be using a main div in component that has following css features

```
 { 
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      right:0;
      left:0;
    }
```

then body will stay behind this div and you can do every modification that you want in this div. But I would really recommend you to use first way.